# How to dynamically change SP in simplesamlphp_auth module for drupal 7?

Tags: php, drupal-7, simplesamlphp

In the simplesaml_auth module basic settings, there is a way to specify which sp to use as an authentication source as shown in the image below

[image: Basic Settings for simplesamlphp_auth]

Instead of having to populate this field every time, I want to have it dynamically populated this according to an environment variable. How can that be done?

Comment: are you able to find out the answer for this? I am having the same exact requirement